# Are these two Proj4 string treated differently? will any argument get ignored or overrided?

Tags: coordinate-system, proj

I have knowledge enough to play around Proj4s string but I have not found any question about this yet.

I have these two Proj4 strings.

`+proj=eqdc +lat_0=39 +lon_0=-96 +lat_1=33 +lat_2=45 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=-0.9956,1.9013,0.5215,0.025915,0.009416,0.0011599,-0.00062 +units=m +no_defs`

and this one below (`+datum=NAD83` is added in front of `+ellps=... +towgs84=...`)

`+proj=eqdc +lat_0=39 +lon_0=-96 +lat_1=33 +lat_2=45 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=-0.9956,1.9013,0.5215,0.025915,0.009416,0.0011599,-0.00062 +units=m +no_deft`

In case you wonder, The 7-parameters argument in both strings is from [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112198/proj4-postgis-transformations-between-wgs84-and-nad83-transformations-in-alask).

I wonder if:

1. In the 2nd string, will `+ellps=... +towgs83=...` override `+datum=NAD83` during transforming projection?
2. I have two file about the same data projected by 1st string and 2nd string. I am going to transform them to any NAD83-based projection or NAD83 latlong(EPSG-4269). Will Proj4 transform the data projected by 2nd string to the new NAD83-based projection with or without datum shift because I had `+datum=NAD83` in the Proj4 string and in front of `+ellps=... +towgs84=...`?

2.1 After projecting 1st-string-projected data and 2nd-string-projected data to the same NAD83 projection, will or will not I have two same results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say how it goes in theory but it is easy to test what happens in practice with gdaltransform utility http://www.gdal.org/gdaltransform.html

```
gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs "+proj=eqdc +lat_0=39 +lon_0=-96 +lat_1=33 +lat_2=45 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=-0.9956,1.9013,0.5215,0.025915,0.009416,0.0011599,-0.00062 +units=m +no_defs"
-80 36
Result:
1429512.75999231 -207252.541637988 1.35481430124491

gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs "+proj=eqdc +lat_0=39 +lon_0=-96 +lat_1=33 +lat_2=45 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=-0.9956,1.9013,0.5215,0.025915,0.009416,0.0011599,-0.00062 +units=m +no_deft"
-80 36
Result:
1429512.75999231 -207252.541637988 1.35481430124491
```

Result is the same to the very last decimal.

Comment: I guess ```+ellips=GRS80 +towgs84=...``` in the latter place overrides the previous ```+datum=NAD83```