# Geographic Transformation in Alaska Between NAD83 (NSRS 2007) and NAD83

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, united-states, nad83

What is the best geographic transformation for Alaska to go from NAD83 to NAD83 (NSRS2007)?

Esri available transformation for GCS_NAD_1983_NSRS2007 to NAD83:

```
WGS_1984_(ITRF00)_To_NAD_1983 + NAD_1983_NSRS2007_To_WGS_1984_1
NAD_1983_To_WGS_1984_5 + NAD_1983_NSRS2007_To_WGS_1984_1
NAD_1983_To_WGS_1984_1 + NAD_1983_NSRS2007_To_WGS_1984_1
```

The suggestion from the below post is to use WGS_1984_(ITRF00)_To_NAD_1983.
 [Geographic Transformations in Alaska Between NAD83 and WGS84](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91414/geographic-transformations-in-alaska-between-nad83-and-wgs84)

Looks like this is still the best option for Alaska for NAD83 to WGS84. I am wondering about the second half of the transformation "chain." Because NAD_1983_NSRS2007_To_WGS_1984_1 is a null transformation it is putting the NAD83 into the WGS84 realization that is tied to ITRF 2000 and then saying that this is equal to NAD83 (NSRS2007). I would think that we would need a transformation "chian" like WGS_1984_(ITRF00)_To_NAD_1983 + WGS_1984_(ITRF00)_To_NAD_1983_CORS96 to account for the change from NAD83 to NAD83 (NSRS2007).

(Transformation parameters can be found in this Esri document:
http://downloads2.esri.com/support/TechArticles/geographic_transformations_1040.pdf)

Comment: As per the [tour] there should be only one question per question.

Comment: @Midavalo I reworded the last part of the post. Can you please take it off hold now?